# I can't fill card data in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait

[image: how page is look like]

Hi guess, today I struggled with a problem I cant fill card data.https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzN22.png
As I understood it appears cuz of nested html(html in html I'm not good in eng). So what do u supposed to do?

I tried to fill it by id, full xpath, selector etc...

Nothing works.

Some code what I used

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "cardCvc-input"))).send_keys("1234")
```

data.https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzN22.png

Comment: data.https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzN22.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch to `iframe` first to access the element.The `input` element present inside an `iframe`.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and following `css` selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='payment']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "cardCvc-input"))).send_keys("1234")
```

---

To come out from `iframe` you need to switch to default_content.

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: DUDE thank u so much u are a hero of my day. Can u pls decribe how to go back from iframe plssss

Comment: @Hush : `driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Comment: yep I wrote Driver.switch_to.default_content() if smb want to know ;)